# Database design in lack of join-like query In MongoDB: how to use refs to documents in other collections

Tags: mongodb, join, rdbms, database

I'm meddling with MongoDB to see how it would do in a real project as a platform for serious data storage, but I have a little problem with understanding the concept, or rather, how the data design should look like. I understand the idea of embedding objects, such as instead of what you would do in a RDBMS, like:

```
PEOPLE (Table):
id | Name
---------
 1 | John
 2 | Steve

PHONES (Table):
id | peopleId | phone
 1 |    1     | 555 66 77
 2 |    1     | 555 66 78
 3 |    2     | 555 11 22
```

In MongoDB, you would create two documents in a collection embedding the detail objects, like:

```
{
  name: "John",
  phones: [
    {phone: "555 66 77"},
    {phone: "555 66 78"}
  ]
},
{
  name: "Steve",
  phones: [
    {phone: "555 11 22"}
  ]
}
```

Now this approach is all good, and would work where detail objects are rather unique per master document (as in each phone belongs to one person only), but once you walk into the realm of (yes!) relations, where details are not strictly unique to their owners, you walk into trouble. Cosider a Book / Author relationship. There are many books, which may have more then one author, while many authors will have more than one book (a many-to-many relationship). If you embed author documents in books, you will have to duplicate authors data as many times as he has books. Same the other way around, if you embed books into authors, you will have duplicate data as many times as that book has authors, ie that same book will appear inside other author documents. Needless to say, this creates a hell of data consistancy issues.

```
{
  book: "A Nice Title",
  authors: [
    {name: "Jane", age: 30},
    {name: "Tom", age: 20}
  ]
},
{
  book: "Some Other Nice Title",
  authors: [
    {name: "Jane", age: 29},
    {name: "Tom", age: 21}
  ]
}
```

Like here, is Jane 30 or 29 years old ?

Now, as I understand reading [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/) , the preferred method to solve this is to keep the sub-document in its own collection and use its _id instead of embedding it (anyone feel like we're back to an RDBMS at this point?), by either doing it manually and query for each document you get for the details (resulting in many many queries for each document, and if you have a list of documents multiply it with your document count!) or use DBRef's which are said to do the exact same thing on a DRIVER level, as opposed to on server level, which means the exact same, just not done by me, but by the driver, so same query number applies, ie: network overhead, server overhead, waiting, waiting... Here is an example:

```
people:
{
  _id: 1,
  name: "John",
  phones: [
    {phones_id: 1},
    {phones_id: 2}
  ]
},
{
  _id: 2,
  name: "Steve",
  phones: [
    {phone_id: 3}
  ]
}
```

phones:

```
{
  _id: 1,
  phone: "555 66 77"
},
{
  _id: 2,
  phone: "555 66 78"
},
{
  _id: 3,
  phone: "555 11 22"
}
```

Which means after the first query from which I get people documents, I'll have to do 3 more queries over phones collection to get the actual phones to produce a list of peoples phone numbers.

Right off the bat in today's data load I can tell you: that is **NOT going to fly**. Imagine that was a **50.000** long book list with 10 authors each ? I'm NOT sending **500.001** queries to a server just to get **one** list.

Constructs like:

```
bookLinks:
{ bookId: 1, authorId: 1}, {bookId: 2, authorId: 1}...
```

will only make matters worse: now you have to do one query for links, an equal number of queries as resulting documents to link them to books, and then a number of queries for authors, resulting in 550.001 queries (for 50000 books with 10 authors each).

So... As any real project will obviously have both embedable (phone book) and non-embedable (authors/books) models, and since MongoDB cannot at server level resolve dbrefs to documents in other collections and embed them, what is the way to go ? What is the correct or preferred way to design document collections in such a scenario ?

I hope I managed to describe my concerns accurate enough.

**Note:** Please don't advise local caching of details to decrease number of queries (no: I still will not send 300.001 queries to a server instead of 500.001). Such methods would be patches for a poor design, they wouldn't solve the problem.

Comment: Yes, if your data is in any way relational, you shouldn't be using mongodb. It'll bite you eventually. Take a look at [this old tale](http://www.sarahmei.com/blog/2013/11/11/why-you-should-never-use-mongodb/)

Comment: "Imagine that was a 50.000 long book list with 10 authors each.  I'm NOT sending 500.001 queries to a server just to get one list." - fetch the 10 authors, collect all theirs phone_id and fetch phones at once. Two queries.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev that seems to be the standard answer, but as I said in the question: any data in any project more complex than a simple school homework will invariably involve relational data. That is unavoidable.

Comment: "That is unavoidable." - so it means that you should _never_ use mongodb, doesn't it? :) Take a look at postgres. A solid rdbms __and__ good free-form json capabilities.

Comment: Agreed, postgresql is indeed great. However, I think that a embedded json nosql system is a much more natural fit for orm systems we use today, like jpa / hibernate etc. I refuse to think MongoDB authors would be unable to see the problem. So I guess I want to believe they have a solution (besides local caching and constructing result locally as you offered).

Comment: Indeed, there is something that can help you in this phone lookup scenario. Take a look at aggregation pipeline and its `$lookup` operator. But I predict that you'll quickly reach its bounds. :)

Comment: did take a look, and it does seem like a solution. Would you care to make it an answer and detail it a bit ? Also, can you use multiple lookups ? Data rarely has single foreign links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some cases, you can do it with aggregation pipeline and [its `$lookup` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/). Something like this (sorry, doc example, not your example)

```
db.orders.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup:
        {
          from: "inventory",
          localField: "item",
          foreignField: "sku",
          as: "inventory_docs"
        }
   }
])
```

Essentially, this is a left-outer join, with a price to pay (more convoluted query syntax). In your case, you might have to `$unwind` your arrays first.

> Also, can you use multiple lookups ?

Yes, it should be as simple as placing several `$lookup` steps in the pipeline.

Comment: A bit busy now, so don't have time to make an aggregate query for your input. Might come back sometime later, but no promises :)

Comment: No problem I can adapt to different examples :) I did see that example in documentation tho, thats why I asked if you can use multiple lookups, like $lookup: {...},{...},{...}. There rarely is a single foreign key in a table. Also, how does this perform speedwise ?

Comment: @TuncayGöncüoğlu "how does this perform speedwise ?" - better than app-level joins. but worse than a mature rdbms :)